# Numbers "of twenty and below" meaning

Tags: numbers

I read that many style guides say that any number (ordinal or cardinal) of twenty or below should be written as a word. However,we often  see the number used for centuries.

It's now the 21st century.
I like the furniture of the 19th century.
He was a monk in the 13th century.

I don't quite understand this explanation. Does it mean that numbers from one to ten, from ten to twenty including twenty are written in words?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. There are other exceptions, though, for example dates.  You might send a text message to a restaurant "I would like to book a table for twelve people on the 15th February 2021." But there are exceptions to the exceptions: for special days, like US independence day (the fourth of  july), you might use words.

Comment: I have never seen the advice that numbers *twenty or below* be written as words.  I've always seen it as *ten or below* (or occasionallly 100 or below).  For example, _Numbers up to nine should always be written in words, anything higher than nine can be written in numeral._ (https://canvas.hull.ac.uk/courses/213/pages/writing-numbers) or _In general, use numerals to express numbers 10 and above_ (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/numbers/numerals)  It really depends on the particular style guide that you're using.